# If f is integrable on $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis

> **Justify:** Let $K$ be the Cantor set. Then the function $$f:[0,1]\to\mathbb R, \ x \mapsto \begin{cases}0\quad\text{if}\
>  x\notin K\\1\quad\text{if}\ x\in K\end{cases}$$ is Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$.

I don't know how to solve.

Comment: By the (Riemann-)Lebesgue Criterion, a function is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ if it is bounded and the set of points at which it is discontinuous has measure zero.  So that gives you a place to start.  (I assume you meant Riemann integrable.  The function is bounded and measurable so is certainly Lebesgue integrable.)

Comment: Are you trying to show Riemann integrability or Lebesgue integrability? Because Lebesgue integrability follows from measurability, and that's obvious.

Comment: Riemann integrablility

Answer (score 4):

**Suggestion**: Let $S \subset [0,1]$ be a set, and let $1_S: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the characteristic function of $S$: namely $1_S(x) = 1$ if $x \in S$; $1_S(x) = 0$ otherwise.  This is certainly a bounded function, so to decide whether it is Riemann integrable, by the (Riemann-)Lebesgue Criterion it is enough to figure out where it is discontinuous.  It is a nice problem to discover this for yourself in terms of $S$.  If you don't see it you can try plenty of examples: finite sets, open and closed intervals, the rational numbers in $[0,1]$, the irrational numbers in $[0,1]$, the Cantor set...

Comment: It's discontinuous only on $K$ and $m(K)=0$ so $f$ is $R$-integrable on $[0,1].$

Comment: Is it correct ?

Comment: Yeah, I think that's correct.

Comment: How did come up with that it is discontinuous precisely on $K$: what properties of $K$ did you use?  As you can see from my answer, I am suggesting that you try to solve a more general problem, but if you can solve that you'll understand better what's going on.

Comment: I used the result http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/457893/f-is-continuous-at-uncountably-many-points-of-0-1-and-discontinuous-at-uncou?rq=1

Comment: Good grief: yes, Brian's answer to your very closely related question answers this question.  (But if you knew that, why were you struggling with this question?  Did you not know/remember the Lebesgue criterion?)  I still claim that answering the more general case set up in my answer would be educational, but I'll leave it open for you and/or other interested parties to think about.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to invoke the Lesbesgue Criterion for Riemann integrability. Here's another way.

First, boundedness is clear, so all we need to show is that for any $\epsilon > 0$, we can find some partition, $P \subset [0,1]$ such that $U(f,P) - L(f,P) < \epsilon$, where $U(f,P)$ is the upper estimate for $\int f$ and $L(f,P)$ is the lower estimate for $\int f$.

Here's the motivation. We want to split off the interval into "good" and "bad" intervals. The "good" intervals is precisely $[0,1] \setminus K$, since $f = 0$ on those intervals. So, the only thing we need to worry about are the "bad" intervals and we'll just try to make the size of the "bad" intervals go to 0.

Let's construct our partition. The cantor set is constructed by repeatedly removing the middle third of each interval. Let $E_n$ be the set of endpoints in the $n^\mbox{th}$ iteration of this construction. Choose $P_n$ to be the partition with endpoints corresponding exactly to those of of $E_n$.

Let $A$ be the intervals in $P_n$ such that $A \cap K = \emptyset$. In other words, $A$ consists of exactly those intervals that do not contain any elements from the Cantor set. Let $B$ be the intervals in $P_n$ such that $B \cap K = K$. It is clear that $A$ and $B$ are disjoint.

We can now finish our proof. It is clear that $U(f,P_n) - L(f,P_n) = 0$ on $A$. Noting that the length of the Cantor set is $(\frac{2}{3})^n$, we have $U(f,P_n) - L(f,P_n) \le (\frac{2}{3})^n$ on $B$.

Hence $U(f,P_n) - L(f,P_n) \le (\frac{2}{3})^n < \epsilon$ for $n$ sufficiently large.